# How can I quickly delete entries that should not exist in the database?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, database

Imports entries from the old database.
I download a specific object by name and these are objects taken from the old database.

Now I check if such an object exists in the new database.

There are, for example, 20 such old objects and 25 in the new base.
How can I automatically remove these 5 objects from the new database?
I tried something by using for e.g.

```py
obj = Model.objects.all()
kr = Model.objects.filter(name=name).first()

obj_list = []
for op in obj:
    if op in obj_list:
        continue
    else:
        obj_list.append(op)

spec_list = []
    for item in obj_list:
        if kr == item:
            continue
        else:
            spec_list.append(item)
```

Comment: It's hard to understand what you want. You want to delete objects from new database that are not in old database?

Answer (score 0):

If you have the object, just delete it with:

```
item.delete()
```

If you can compare objects from one with another, it should be as easy, as that.

```
old_objects   # list with objects from old db
new_objects = Model.objects.all()

for my_object in new_objects:
    if my_object not in old_objects:
        my_object.delete()
```